# How to use useDeprecatedNdk with Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio-3.0

My app using android-ndk. I want to use useDeprecatedNdk with android studio 3. Is it possible?

I add `android.useDeprecatedNdk = true` to gradle.properties file. But I get below error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileFlav1ReleaseNdk'.
> Error: Flag android.useDeprecatedNdk is no longer supported and will be removed in the next version of Android Studio.  Please switch to a supported build system.
  Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
   https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html#ndkCompile
   To get started, you can use the sample ndk-build script the Android
   plugin generated for you at:
   /project-path/build/intermediates/ndk/flav1/release/Android.mk
  Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
   https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html
  To continue using the deprecated NDK compile for another 60 days, set 
  android.deprecatedNdkCompileLease=1562444227185 in gradle.properties

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Well, did you do what it suggested at the end? I.e. _"set 
  android.deprecatedNdkCompileLease=1562444227185 in gradle.properties"_

Comment: yes, every build fails. every failure build suggest a new number for deprecatedNdkCompileLease :D

Comment: It's time to accept the inevitable upgrade